# GWT requestfactory: can user fabricate the setter method of entity proxy?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I use request factory in my app, the client side proxy contain getter methods and some setter methods that user can modify, however for security reason, some of the setter methods is not exposed, I'd like to know is it possible that, user from client side, is able to fabricate the setter method to modify the entity?

If so, anybody know how to solve the security risk of this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is one important rule to remember in web-development:

> **You should never trust the client**

The user has all the means to access data on the client and also modify it. It could also generate some arbitrary `RequestFactory` payload and send it directly to the backend without even using your app.

So the only solution is to secure the backend and make sure that the currently logged in user is allowed to call the `setter` (i.e using AOP, etc)